# Why am I getting this error: SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function trunc(timestamp without time zone) does not exist?

Tags: postgresql

Here is my code where my error is occurring.

```
    WHERE edv.ztab0000mn.cdc_oper_cd = 'D' AND DATE(edv.ztab0000mn.cdc_dt) = TRUNC(TO_TIMESTAMP('<DATA_EFF_STRT_DT variable place holder>', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')::TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE) AND edv.ztab0000mn.load_dt = TO_TIMESTAMP('<LOAD_DT variable place holder>', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')
```

I tried removing the `WITHOUT TIME ZONE` portion and it's still throwing the same error. I replaced `'<DATA_EFF_STRT_DT variable place holder>'`  with the name of the column and it said "column "data_eff_strt_dt" does not exist and cannot be referenced in this part of the query"

Is that the issue or is it the timezone issue?

Here is the full query:

```
UPDATE edv.core_cust_rep_capc_hs
SET load_end_dt = stg.load_dt, data_eff_end_dt = stg.data_eff_strt_dt
FROM edv.core_cust_rep_capc_hs AS dv
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT
    COALESCE(edv.but000.bpext, '-1') AS core_cust_id, COALESCE(edv.ztab0000mn.record_id, '[NULL IN SOURCE]') AS src_rcd_id, edv.ztab0000mn.load_dt AS load_dt, edv.ztab0000mn.cdc_dt AS data_eff_strt_dt, edv.ztab0000mn.data_src_nm AS data_src_nm, edv.ztab0000mn.parent_id AS src_prnt_id, edv.ztab0000mn.zzfld00009s AS bus_ptnr_rlt_type_cd, edv.ztab0000mn.zzfld00009t AS rlt_grp_nbr, edv.ztab0000mn.zzfld00009v AS src_data_eff_end_dt, edv.ztab0000mn.zzfld00009u AS src_data_eff_strt_dt, edv.ztab0000mn.zzfld0000c8 AS poa_rlt_cncl_rsn_cd, edv.ztab0000mn.zzfld0000ce AS ot_rsn_txt, edv.ztab0000mn.zzfld0000cf AS stip_txt, edv.ztab0000mn.zzfld0000cg AS rep_capc_stat_cd, edv.ztab0000mn.zzfld0000ei AS sgn_ct, edv.ztab0000mn.zzfld0000eo AS ogc_rvw_dt, edv.ztab0000mn.zzfld0000kw AS fdry_agr_nbr, edv.ztab0000mn.zzfld0000mo AS rlt_bus_ptnr_nbr, edv.ztab0000mn.zzfld0000n0 AS sap_src_cd, edv.ztab0000mn.zzfld0000dr AS url_l, edv.ztab0000mn.zzfld0000ks AS rcd_ofc, TO_TIMESTAMP('9999-12-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS data_eff_end_dt, TO_TIMESTAMP('9999-12-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS load_end_dt, md5(CONCAT_WS('', TRIM(edv.but000.bpext :: varchar), '~~', TRIM(edv.ztab0000mn.record_id :: varchar), '~~', TRIM(edv.ztab0000mn.parent_id :: varchar), '~~', TRIM(edv.ztab0000mn.zzfld00009s :: varchar), '~~', TRIM(edv.ztab0000mn.zzfld00009t :: varchar), '~~', TO_CHAR(edv.ztab0000mn.zzfld00009v, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '~~', TO_CHAR(edv.ztab0000mn.zzfld00009u, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '~~', TRIM(edv.ztab0000mn.zzfld0000c8 :: varchar), '~~', TRIM(edv.ztab0000mn.zzfld0000ce :: varchar), '~~', TRIM(edv.ztab0000mn.zzfld0000cf :: varchar), '~~', TRIM(edv.ztab0000mn.zzfld0000cg :: varchar), '~~', TRIM(edv.ztab0000mn.zzfld0000ei :: varchar), '~~', TO_CHAR(edv.ztab0000mn.zzfld0000eo, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '~~', TRIM(edv.ztab0000mn.zzfld0000kw :: varchar), '~~', TRIM(edv.ztab0000mn.zzfld0000mo :: varchar), '~~', TRIM(edv.ztab0000mn.zzfld0000n0 :: varchar), '~~', TRIM(edv.ztab0000mn.zzfld0000dr :: varchar), '~~', TRIM(edv.ztab0000mn.zzfld0000ks :: varchar))) AS hash_dif, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COALESCE(edv.ztab0000mn.record_id, '[NULL IN SOURCE]') ORDER BY edv.ztab0000mn.cdc_dt DESC, edv.ztab0000mn.ods_cre_dt DESC, edv.ztab0000mn.ods_upd_dt DESC) AS row_num_part
    FROM edv.ztab0000mn
    JOIN edv.but000
        ON (edv.ztab0000mn.parent_id = edv.but000.partner_guid AND edv.but000.bpext IS NOT NULL)
    JOIN edv.tb002
        ON (edv.but000.bu_group = edv.tb002.bu_group AND edv.tb002.spras = 'E' AND edv.tb002.txt15 = 'Customer' AND edv.tb002.cdc_oper_cd IN ('I', 'UN', 'D'))
    WHERE edv.ztab0000mn.cdc_oper_cd = 'D' AND DATE(edv.ztab0000mn.cdc_dt) = TRUNC(TO_TIMESTAMP(data_eff_strt_dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')::TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE) AND edv.ztab0000mn.load_dt = TO_TIMESTAMP('<LOAD_DT variable place holder>', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') 
    ORDER BY edv.ztab0000mn.cdc_dt) AS stg
    ON COALESCE(stg.src_rcd_id, 'DFLT') = COALESCE(dv.src_rcd_id, 'DFLT')
    WHERE core_cust_rep_capc_hs.load_dt <> stg.load_dt AND core_cust_rep_capc_hs.load_end_dt = TO_TIMESTAMP('9999-12-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND stg.row_num_part = 1
```

Error:

```
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function trunc(timestamp without time zone) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 2833
```

Comment: Try converting that to a string first

Comment: because a timestampo is no string and will never have spaces to trim in the first place

Comment: Where in the manual did you find the timestamp function trunk() ? I see a function date_trunc(), but no trunc()

Comment: i tried converting this to a string by doing this TRUNC(TO_TIMESTAMP('<DATA_EFF_STRT_DT variable place holder>', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF' :: varchar)::TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE) but it still threw the same error

Comment: Add tables and data as ddl and show what you try to achieve

Comment: trunc() is not a (standard) PostgreSQL function. Unless you created it or installed it from other source, you can't use this. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using **[DATE_TRUNC](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-datetime.html#functions-datetime-trunc)**

Example:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('precision', 'your_date') AS date FROM table
```

**1st argument is precision.**

More [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/postgresql-date_trunc-function/).